# Unable to post data to controller's action method using Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to Post a `Partial` View's data to the server to save the input fields result to database and then return back to the same (partial view which is open as a modal dialog) or return to the parent view which called the modal dialog.

But for some reason, I am not getting the Action method's parameter (i.e. weldMaster) in the Controller which is being sent from the ajax method call.

Here is my controller method.

```
    // GET: WeldMasters/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? ids, bool isPartials = false)
    {
        if (ids == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        WeldMaster weldMaster = db.WeldMasters.Find(ids);
        ViewBag.Readonly = false;
        if (weldMaster == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        if(isPartials)
            return PartialView(weldMaster);
        else
            return View(weldMaster);
    }

    // POST: WeldMasters/Details/5
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult Details**(WeldMaster weldMaster)** 
    //{"The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'IMCC_PAS.Entities.WeldMaster' failed because no type converter can convert between these types."}
    {
        var success = 0;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            success = 1;
            db.Entry(weldMaster).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new { success });
        }
        return Json(new { success });
    }
```

Here is the ajax code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".saveBtn").click(function (e) {
            debugger;
            var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
            // If I dont pass the token in the `data` parameter of ajax, then action method of controller is not called at all.            
e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("Details", "WeldMasters")',
                data: { __RequestVerificationToken: token, weldMaster: $('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm').serialize() },
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(result.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(result.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the modal for the partial view

```
@model IMCC_PAS.Entities.WeldMaster
```

and here is the form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "__AjaxAntiForgeryForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.weld_no, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.rep_no, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.length, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.normal_size, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3  col-sm-12">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.weld_no, ViewBag.Readonly ? (object)new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control" } } : new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3  col-sm-12">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.rep_no, ViewBag.Readonly ? (object)new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control" } } : new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3  col-sm-12">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.length, ViewBag.Readonly ? (object)new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control" } } : new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3  col-sm-12">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.normal_size, ViewBag.Readonly ? (object)new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control" } } : new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div> 

        <div class="form-group modal-footer">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <a class="saveBtn" href="javascript:void(0);">Edit</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
}
```

**EDIT:** Here is the parent view which has the selection parameters for showing the weld details. And then Weld details are shown in a div (for readonly purpose) and can be edited in a popup modal dialog on a button click.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        ... more code for other dropdowns here

        //When Wled No is changed, reload Weld Details in its respective Partial view
        $("#weldddl").change(function () {

            var parameter = { ids: $("#weldddl").val(), isPartials: true };
            $.ajax({
                url: '/WeldMasters/Details/',
                type: 'GET',
                data: parameter,
                success: function (result) {
                    var div = $('#weldDetails');
                    div.html('');
                    div.html(result);
                }
            });
        });

        $(".editWeldBtn").click(function () {
            //debugger;
            $('#MyModal').empty();
            $('#MyModal').append(GetModalDialog());
            var link = '@Url.Action("Details", "WeldMasters")';
            data = { ids: $("#weldddl").val(), isPartials: true };
            LaunchModalDlg(link, data, "View Weld Master Information", "75%");
        });

    });
</script>

<h4>Index</h4>
<script src="~/Scripts/MyScripts.js"></script>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") | 
    <a class="editWeldBtn" href="javascript:void(0);">Edit</a>
</p>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Discipline, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Discipline, (SelectList)ViewBag.disciplines, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "disciplineddl" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Discipline, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DrawingNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DrawingNo, (SelectList)ViewBag.drawings, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "drawingddl" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DrawingNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ComponentNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ComponentNo, (SelectList)ViewBag.components, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "componentddl" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ComponentNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WeldNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.WeldNo, (SelectList)ViewBag.components, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "weldddl" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WeldNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9" id="weldDetails"> <!--This is for showing the partial view for showing weld details-->
    </div>
    <div id="MyModal"></div> <!--This is for pop up modal dialog-->
</div>
```

Comment: Its just `data: $('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm').serialize(),` - the `serialize()` method serializes all the form controls including the token

Comment: You're passing `weldMaster: $('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm').serialize()` but `weldMaster` itself is a viewmodel argument - `$('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm').serialize()` is enough to serialize form contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are serializing the full form then you don't need to send explicitly anti forgery token.

use this:

```
 data: $('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm').serialize(),
```

Comment: with this I do get the weldMaster in the action method but only with the original values that were posted. The changed values do not show up

Comment: @WAQ. `.serialize()` serializes the values of the form controls, so if your getting the original values it means you have not edited anything in the view

Comment: @StephenMuecke you are right. I just found out that the problem is the way I have laid the controls in my application. My main view has selection parameters (drop downs). then after the right selection is made, the details of weld are showing in a div(which hosts a partial view). this is readonly div. But there is a button which shows the same partial view in a popup modal dialog. if I have both div and partial dialog on parent view, then the contents are not getting posted back to the controller. If i remove one of two, then it works fine. Can you plz see the updates in the question?

Comment: @WAQ, You have confused me. Are your saying that `div class="col-sm-9" id="weldDetails">` and `<div id="MyModal"></div>` will both contain the partial you have shown? If so why would you do that (but it explains why - because duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html, and `$('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm')` will only ever get the first one (from the first `<div>`, not the modal)

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes our requirement is to show in the div as read only to those users who do not have edit authorizations and the popup modal to those who can edit. What is the proper way to achieve this? and Im sorry I didnot understand this duplicate id thing u mentioned?

Comment: Your html in the first `<div>` should be a different partial that includes just text, (e.g. `@Html.DisplayFor()`, not form controls (and you can get rid of those `ViewBag.Readonly ? ...` conditional attributes) There is no point degrading performance by including all that extra html for the 'read-only' view